# Calculate total spent time exclude pauses

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have kind of log table. It hold records with tasks, status and time when triggered:

**Table tblwork:**

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
| task        | status     | stime               | id  |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
| A           | 1          | 2018-03-07 20:00:00 | 1   |
| A           | 2          | 2018-03-07 20:30:00 | 2   |
| A           | 1          | 2018-03-07 21:00:00 | 3   |
| A           | 3          | 2018-03-07 21:30:00 | 4   |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Status 1 means start, 2 - pause, 3 - end.

So far I try something like this:

```
SELECT x1.stime, SUM(TIMEDIFF(x2.stime, x1.stime))
FROM tblwork AS x1 
LEFT JOIN tblwork AS x2
ON x1.id = x2.id + 1
WHERE x1.`status` = 1 OR x1.`status` = 3
```

But this gave result -6.000?!?!

I need to calculate total time spent for task but to exclude pause. So the final result should be 01:00:00. Is it possible to do that on this way or should I change table and logic?

**UPDATE : SOLUTION**

I think I found right way to do exact what I want:

```
 SELECT id, stime,
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
    (SELECT MAX(stime) FROM tblwork WHERE stime < t.stime),
    stime
  )) AS TotalTime
FROM tblwork as t
where (t.status = 1 or t.status = 3)
```

Comment: should be 01:00:00 ..  the diff

Comment: why task A has two starts (status = 1)?

Comment: because task A started (1) and then paused (2) then unpaused - continued with work (1) and then end (3).

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data you should join only the x1.status = 1 and left join the x2.status=2 or 3

```
  SELECT x1.stime, SUM(TIMEDIFF(x2.stime, x1.stime))
  FROM tblwork AS x1 
  LEFT JOIN tblwork AS x2 ON x1.id = x2.id + 1 
        AND (x2.status = '2' OR x2.status = '3')
  WHERE x1.`status` = 1
```